# Set path parameter without affecting payload using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

First of all I want to mention that I have been digging around a lot for this. I am unable to find a simple and straight forward answer even in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). (Call me dumb if you will, in case it IS mentioned in the docs! I can't seem to find it anyway.)

The thing is, I want to make a PUT request to a URL of the form

```
app.constant('URL_REL_VENDOR_PRODUCTS', '/api/vendor/:vendorId/products/:productId');
```

But I do not want to put the `vendorId` parameter in the request payload. My service layer looks something like this:

```
services.factory('VendorProductService', function($resource, UserAccountService, URL_BASE, URL_REL_VENDOR_PRODUCTS) {
    return $resource(URL_BASE + URL_REL_VENDOR_PRODUCTS, {
        vendorId: UserAccountService.getUser().vendorId,
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
});
```

I know that instead of the `vendorId: UserAccountService.getUser().vendorId` I could have written something along the lines `vendorId: '@vendorId'` but then that pollutes my payload doesn't it?

I don't want to keep the mechanism I am already using in the example as the mechanism does not work when you switch accounts i.e.,if the `UserAccountService.getUser()` is updated. Basically I'm having to reload the entire page to get the service initialized again.

In short, the question is, as the title suggests, how do I set the path parameter `vendorId` without using a service like the one in the snippet and also without modifying the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parameter value a function:

```
services.factory('VendorProductService', function($resource, UserAccountService, URL_BASE, URL_REL_VENDOR_PRODUCTS) {
    return $resource(URL_BASE + URL_REL_VENDOR_PRODUCTS, {
        vendorId: function () {
            return UserAccountService.getUser().vendorId
        },
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### paramDefaults (optional)
>
> Default values for url parameters. These can be overridden in actions methods. **If a parameter value is a function, it will be executed every time** when a param value needs to be obtained for a request (unless the param was overridden).

-- [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Wow! This was driving me crazy. Guess I'm an idiot after all! :|